# How do I prepare models for baking in Marmoset Toolbag 3?

Tags: uv, normals, baking

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to baking, but I understand that the models must be unwrapped. When baking in Marmoset, I don't see anywhere to import any kind of UV mesh. Could someone walk me through how to set up models for baking?

Comment: UV data is an integral part of mesh data and seamlessly exported with it natively by most 3D interchange formats. No additional external file or extra data is required.

Comment: This question does not seem to be about Blender as described in the help center.